# How can I use the sound_generator plugin for flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, package, flutter-plugin

I tried it

```
OutlinedButton(
                onPressed: () => {
                      SoundGenerator.setFrequency(6000),
                      SoundGenerator.setVolume(1),
                      SoundGenerator.play(),
                    })
```

But this didn't play the sound. I search on internet but I can't find any source
This is the official web site for plugin => https://pub.dev/packages/sound_generator

Comment: What do you mean you cannot find a source? Did you check the "example" on the package page you linked?

Answer (score 0):

You need to init it in initState() like:

```
initState(){
...
SoundGenerator.init(96000);
SoundGenerator.setWaveType(waveTypes.SINUSOIDAL);
...
}
```